# WSE1608 error

Tags: iis

We are reciving this message:

> WASE1608: No XOP parts were located
>   in the stream for the specified
>   content-id:

This happens on one machine in the office when an application is trying to connect to a webservice.  The server is a windows 2003 iis 6 webservice and the client is an xp system.

Comment: Would be useful to know what OS this is on, what application was running when the error occurred and what app generated the error.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but is for the benefit of Google users: WSE is obsolete. It should not be used for any new development, unless there is no choice at all. The only features of WSE that have not been superseded by WCF are those that are, themselves, obsolete: DIME, MTOM are examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is the top level error message that WSE 3 will give when it is returning a SOAP fault error message.  Our vendor had to debug the webservice traffic and a crash dump to get the full error message which in our case was a time syncronization issue and sure enough this clients system clock was 3 days behind the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the complaint coming from a .NET client that's connecting to an Apache Axis2 1.3 server? In this case, there appears to be a bug in Apache Axis2 1.3.  You may want to try -- for the sake of experiment, upgrading to Axis2 1.4 or downgrading to Axis2 1.2.

From what I've found on the Internet, you may also want to try replacing the Axiom JARs in your Apache Axis installation with the latest JARs to see if this helps resolve the problem.

Comment: I updated my question but our systems are windows with IIS.  All I could find was Apache to .net issues when I Googled for this.